# How do I make Talvas Fathyron stock up his merchant inventory?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dragonborn

Whenever I try to buy something from [Talvas Fathryon](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Dragonborn:Talvas_Fathryon), he shows me that he has absolutely nothing to sell:

[image: Talvas Fathryon shows his merchant inventory but does not sell anything.]

This happened after I told Talvas to part ways with me (leave as a follower), and when I visited him at the Tel Mithryn Tower. I'm pretty sure that it's been more than 48 hours (so his merchant inventory should have reset by now), and I also don't recall buying out all his items (so he still should have a few items in his inventory). I have previously hired Talvas as a follower and remember viewing his non-empty merchant inventory before.

I would like to buy stuff from him as the ["Talvas Fathryon" UESP wiki article states](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Dragonborn:Talvas_Fathryon) that "*Talvas' store contains an extensive collection of standard Skyrim Destruction and Conjuration spell tomes, as well as tomes for additional spells added by the Dragonborn DLC*".

The notes of the ["Talvas Fathryon" UESP wiki article](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Dragonborn:Talvas_Fathryon) state that: "*if you hire Talvas as your steward, his trade inventory will become inaccessible*". However, I have not hired him as a steward.

I am playing on the PC and with mods ([mod list here](http://tny.cz/7e54fdae)).

**How do I make Talvas sell stuff again?**

Answer (score 2):

As quoted from the [Skyrim Wikia page on Talvas Fathryon](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Talvas_Fathryon):

> Talvas may stop selling goods including spell tomes. Cause unknown but may have to do with using him as a follower. This makes any spells that can only be bought from Talvas unobtainable. This can never be resolved on consoles making it impossible to buy his unique spell tomes.

This implies that if you are playing on the PC you can obviously gain these items via console commands.

Comment: I see. I know that I can get items through console commands. But I would like to know of a way to 'fix' Talvas instead, as I prefer to buy items or get them normally through the game, rather than add them through console commands.

Comment: According to the Wikia, there isn't a way to fix this problem other than fixing it yourself through the console.  As I said you can either spawn the items in for yourself or alternatively you can try simply finding a list of his inventory and then giving him all of the items again via this console command: additem <ItemID> <#> - Whether or not he will actually SELL the items given to him via the console command, I don't know. I believe the answer I gave is sufficient however: This is a bug without a real fix.

Comment: I was thinking that there might be a fix not mentioned in the TES wikis, which is why I asked here.

Answer (score 1):

The [Talvas Fathryon Talk Page](http://uesp.net/wiki/Dragonborn_talk:Talvas_Fathryon) over at the Unofficial Elder Scrolls Pages has the following little tidbit by the user MadAndyD:

> Though Talvas fulfills all these roles, he seems to do a poor job of
>   multitasking. He only trains and sells whilst in the proximity of Tel
>   Mithryn, but, it seems that even when in the proximity of Tel Mithryn,
>   as a follower he cannot sell, with the relevant window instead showing
>   his inventory, as if you were to trade with him. However, dismissing
>   him did not seem to instantly fix his merchant screen, nor did waiting
>   for his stock to reset, I was only able to fix this by recruiting
>   another follower altogether, and then visiting him.

Give it a try.